# Next.js 13 routes inside parallel routes cause infinite rendering in dev mode

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Page route inside a parallel route rerenders infinitely in dev mode.

**app directory:**

```
app
├── page-with-parallel
│   ├── @parallelroute
│   │   └── page-inside-parallel
│   │       └── page.js
│   └── layout.js
├── globals.css
├── layout.js
└── page.js
```

**app/page-with-parallel/layout.js:**

```js
export default function Layout({ parallelroute }) {
    console.log('foo')
    return (
        <div>
            {parallelroute}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**app/page-with-parallel/@parallelroute/page-inside-parallel/page.js:**

```js
export default function Page() {
    console.log('bar');
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Bar</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

run in dev mode and go to localhost:3000/page-with-parallel/page-inside-parallel

expected output:

```bash
foo
bar
```

actual output:

```bash
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
foo
bar
foo
foo
bar
(this goes on infinitely)
```

Comment: check this out https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by updating next to **v13.4.10** released 18 hours before this question.